# MsiOpenDatabase does not open an MSI-file (error code 110)

Tags: c#, .net, wix, windows-installer

I have a strange effect here. 
I'm trying to open an existing MSI-file using DTF assembly and it return error code 110 (ERROR_OPEN_FAILED). If I'm trying to get last error by MsiGetLastErrorRecord - it returns 0, i.e. there is no error.

For experiment, I've tried to open the same file using WinAPI directly (from a C++ application) and it works fine.

As far as I know DTF is used by a lot of people and I suppose there is no bug in it, so it should be some issue with my system/configuration.

I'm using Windows 10 and VS2012 with .NET 4.5

Any hints, what it could be?

PS: actually, from beginning I've tried to interop WinAPI by myself and I've got this result. Using of DTF was a try to illuminate my eventually wrong interoption.

**Update**: I've checked execution with ProcessMonitor and have seen that CreateFile fails with SHARING VIOLATION:
Desired Access: Generic Read/Write
Disposition:    Open
Options:    Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File
Attributes: N
ShareMode:  Read
AllocationSize: n/a

**Update 2:** it was one of the most stuipid errors. The issue was because a property, that had opened a DB, was triggered from design mode. 
Now the issue is solved. Thank you all for help!

Comment: It looks like your update should be an answer: the file is already open elsewhere. If this surprises you, you should add more details about the scenario, including why you think it shouldn't already be open.

Comment: I agree with Michael, the file must have a lock on it. Can you post the actual code you use as well? Did you try to open the file read-only?

Answer (score 0):

**From the DTF help file**:

```
using (Database db = new Database("product.msi", DatabaseOpenMode.ReadOnly))
    {        string value = (string) db.ExecuteScalar(
        "SELECT `Value` FROM `Property` WHERE `Property` = '{0}'", propName);
    }
```

This should obviously work in **read-only mode** regardless if the file is locked elsewhere. There is also the convenient **InstallPackage class** that works with files and cabinets in the context of a compressed or uncompressed product layout:

```
using (InstallPackage pkg = new InstallPackage("d:\builds\product.msi",
DatabaseOpenMode.Transact))     
{
   //(find the rest of the sample in the DTF help file)
}
```

I would try both classes with the different **DatabaseOpenModes** (*ReadOnly*, *Transact*, *Direct*, *Create*, *CreateDirect*).